# De-obfuscate Javascript code to make it readable

Tags: javascript

Hi i need deobfuscate this code. But i cant, i use deobfuscator from everywhere and cant.

The code is here: http://textsaver.flap.tv/lists/1jtr

Thanks all for help me :)

Comment: This is a job for Google. Not Stack Overflow.

Comment: Developer Tools in Chrome already does that built in. Load the site which loads the minified JS, find it in the Sources tab and click "Pretty print" in the bottom status bar.

Comment: It's open source. Just go look at it on GitHub. https://github.com/select2/select2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code is not really obfuscated but is in fact "minified". You can use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org) and install a plugin like "[JSTool](http://www.sunjw.us/jstoolnpp/)". Then, open the plugin's menu and using "JSFormat" will reformat the Javascript so you can read it easily.

There is also some extensions for Firefox and Chrome that can also be used. This one here is the best one I could find: [JavaScript and CSS Code Beautifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/javascript-and-css-code-b/iiglodndmmefofehaibmaignglbpdald) (For Google Chrome)

---

Note:

Just in case you are curious, you can click [here](http://stunnix.com/prod/jo/sample.shtml) to see an example of a real obfuscated Javascript. Some of these scripts are very easy to reveal while some others are a lot more sophisticated. It is even possible to hide your javascript code inside an image by converting every character into pixel color values. (Source: ["A technique for hiding your JavaScript Code"](https://www.patrick-wied.at/blog/a-technique-for-hiding-your-javascript-code))

Comment: Thanks bro. You are the best!